# How do I override the value type for specific keys of an object?

Tags: typescript

I'm working on improving the typings for the `xlsx` library. I have the following definition:

```
export interface IWorkSheet {
    [cell: string]: IWorkSheetCell;
}
```

However, certain keys of `IWorkSheet` are used for metadata which is not an `IWorkSheetCell`; for example, `!merges` is an array of `IRange`s instead. I therefore try the following definition:

```
export interface IWorkSheet {
    [cell: string]: IWorkSheetCell;
    ['!merges']?: IRange[];
}
```

Unfortunately, this results in the error "Property '`['!merges']`' of type '`IRange[]`' is not assignable to type IWorkSheetCell." I can get around this by declaring it as `IWorkSheetCell | any`  instead, but this breaks autocomplete and doesn't really reflect the intent of the declaration.

How can I declare the default value type of an object and then override it for specific keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with an `interface`, but with an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```
type IWorkSheet = {
    [cell: string]: IWorkSheetCell;
} & {
    ['!merges']?: IRange[];
}
```

Or:

```
interface IWorkSheet {
    [cell: string]: IWorkSheetCell;
}

type IWorkSheetMerges = IWorkSheet & { ['!merges']?: IRange[]; }
```

Comment: For more details on this not being viable on an interface see the [angular .d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/angular/index.d.ts#L349) and the relevant [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/272)

Comment: What's the practical difference between an interface and an object type that makes this possible with an intersection but not an interface?The issue that @Paarth links points out that this can cause Typescript to "make promises it can't keep": it seems pretty good about figuring out what to expect, but if you for example do `worksheet[prompt('cell?')]` it will assume an IWorkSheetCell even though you could answer `!merges` and get back a completely different type.

Comment: Honestly, I don't the reasoning behind allowing this for `type` but not `interface`. As for your example, `prompt()` returns string, so you have a string index lookup with `worksheet[prompt()]`. Even though a `prompt()` *could* return the string `"!merges"` there's no way for TS to know this at compile-time, thus the return *type* is just `string`; `prompt()` could return any string (or null).